# No entiendo el funcionamiento del siguiente bucle for en python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Estoy empezando en la programación con *Python* y no logro entender la parte de código que indica `for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):`, precisamente no comprendo la parte de "*-1, -1, -1*". Acá les dejo el ejercicio en donde estaba viendo esto:

```
word = input("Introduce una palabra: ")
for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
    print(word[i])
```

Agradecería si me pueden explicar un poco cómo funciona esa parte de código y enq ué situaciones se utiliza.

Comment: el rango va desde  24 hasta 0, en matemáticas se expresa así[24.-1) y decreciendo de 1 en 1 ,es lo mismo que decir que el paso es -1

Comment: Para cada valor en ese rango I=24 i=23 hasta i=0

Comment: muestro la letra de la palabra que esta en la posición i

Comment: Por tanto, mostrara la palabra (arbalap) invertida

Comment: rango(desde,hasta,paso)

Comment: for (i=desde, i>hasta, i=i-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):

es lo mismo

for (i=len(word)-1, i>-1, i=i-1)

len(word)-1 es porque los incides empiezan en 0 y así apuntas a la ultima letra.

El ultimo (-1) se utiliza para hacer un recorrido descendente de mas a menos